# Is there a way to see if at least one object in a class had an attribute at a certain value?

Tags: python, oop

Very new to python and programming in general and am having a blast so far! Just wanted to know if there were some way to see if a certain variable had the same value as an attribute that any object in another instance has. Don't think I did the best job at explaining it, so here's some code that I whipped up!

```
class Something:
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.value = val

a_variable = 1

if a_variable == any_object_of_the_Something_class_with_equal.value:
        print("Hello world!")
```

Comment: I assume by `any_object_of_the_Something_class`, you mean some iterable of instances?

Comment: Note that one usual "caveat" to this kind of setup is that "you shouldn't have to do this if you keep track of all objects that are being created". In the sense that could all the instances not have been collected in a list while they were being created perhaps? That would allow for iteration when you need to find a particular object and so on.

Comment: You can check whether an instance of a class has a named attribute with the [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) built-in function. So if you keep a list of instances that are created, you can check through the list and use it on each one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python and am still sorta getting used to the terms. What I mean with 'any_object_of_the_Something_class.value' was that I wanted to check and see if there were one or more objects in Something whose self.value attribute was equal to the variable. Don't know if that answers the question, but I hope it clears something up yatu!

Comment: Oh, how would lists help here? Sorry, it's sorta hard for me to understand.

Comment: Read [how to use lists in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet). Your condition becomes: `if any([s.value == 1 for s in list_of_Something]):`